# Pentaho report with dynamic Excel as source

Tags: report, pentaho

I have created one report using Pentaho report designer using Excel sheet as data source.

The requirement is the source Excel data will be changed everyday, and we have generated the PRD report based on that.

My question is: do we have to re create the report every time we change the source Excel.

Please note that I am not using Pentaho ba server and only PRD and PDI is installed in my machine.

Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the excel does not change (column names, etc) you have to configure the `Excel input` step with the fixed values for them. If they change you need to assign them as variables to `Excel input` step. Either way you don't need to recreate the transformation. If you get the same values even after you change the source then definitely it should be due to caching. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472555/why-do-i-need-to-refresh-pentaho-report-data-cache-everytime-there-is-a-change-i/29475246#29475246) to disable chaching in PRD. Hope this helps.